# Error running file in Container "error when loading shared libraries" DOCKER

Tags: copy, docker, executable, dockerfile

So I am building an image from a dockerfile, using the COPY command to copy a local file from host into my container. After the image is build I run an interactive shell, and test my file which I copied and am having an error.

Here is my shell information.

```
arcolombo@arcolombo:~/Documents/bedgraph_dockerfile$ sudo docker info
Containers: 18
Images: 72
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 108
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-33-generic
Username: arcolombo
Registry: [https://index.docker.io/v1/]
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER anthonycolombo60@gmail.com
COPY software /bin
```

Note that under my directory where my Dockerfile is contained, I placed my "software" directory, which has a bedWiggle executable in the Dockerfile's context, so it does get loaded into my new container of which my image creates.

This shows the successful completion of the image

```
arcolombo@arcolombo:~/Documents/bed_dockerfile$ sudo docker build        -t="arcolombo" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.7 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
---> d0955f21bf24
Step 1 : MAINTAINER anthonycolombo60@gmail.com
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 5el36a81f34
     Step 2 : COPY software /bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1llhh2e278683ea
Successfully built 1hhfjjeea
```

Yet I get the error when I enter the container built by the above image and running my executable

root@hhhlf75hhhhfcb87ccfa:/bin# ./bedWigggle 
./bedWiggle: error while loading shared libraries: libkrb5.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is - you have copied over the executable, but it has dependencies on various libraries (including `libkrb5.so.3`) that aren't in the container.

You have two choices; you can add the dependencies to the container or you can recompile the executable so that it is statically linked.

You can run the `ldd` tool on the executable to discover which dependencies it requires. You can then either copy the libraries directly into the container as you did with the executable or (probably better) you can find which package the dependencies are from and install with `apt-get`.

Comment: thank you very much.  I clearly did not understand/ nor recognize that that was a package dependency.  I thought it was some sort of internal error.

Comment: Can you please clarify "recompile the executable so that it is statically linked".  How would I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: That's a whole new question really. It just means the executable doesn't depend on dynamic libraries like libc and is self-contained. How to do this is language dependent (and won't be possible for languages dependent on a runtime or interpreter). Try just googling for static binary support in your language and open a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it appears that the shared library required by your executable (bedWiggle) is missing (libkrb5.so.3).

One way to resolve this issue is:

1. Use "COPY" command inside Dockerfile to copy the shared libraries/dependencies inside the container.
   Example: COPY *{local_path} {docker_path}*
2. Set the environment variable where shared libraries are searched for first before the standard set of directories. For instance for Linux based OS, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used. Environment variables can be set via [Docker's Environment replacement (ENV)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)
   Example: ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=*{docker_path}*:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Other is to statically link your dependencies (language dependent).